# Correct syntax for $(this label) jQuery

Tags: jquery, syntax, this

I want to write something for each class select this label and do not display it.

```
$('.no_show_on_form').each(function()
    {
        $(this label).css('display','none');
    });
```

It actually return false.

How could I write my syntax correctly?

--

EDIT#1 : I have tried this other way by using closest() function but it does not seems to return an error or either works.

```
$('.no_show_on_form').each(function()
{
    $(this).closest('label').css('display','none');
});
```

Comment: Add code to understand the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are looking for this -

```
$('label',this).css('display','none');
```

Comment: Hi @pXL, I used the solution above because I am more familiar with this solution instead of your. But thx, I'm sure it will help someone else someday.

Answer (score 1):

Selectors are strings.

You need to call jQuery's traversal methods to explore the element:

```
$(this).find('label')
```

Answer (score 1):

If `.no_show_on_form` is some kind of container, then use context:

```
$('label', this).hide();
```

If `.no_show_on_form` is a form element, you'll need to be a bit more creative:

```
$('.no_show_on_form').each(function(i,el) {
    if (el.id) {
        $('label[for="' + el.id + '"]').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.no_show_on_form').each(function()
{
    $(this).find('label').css('display','none');
});
```

The correct syntax was to use the function find().

**Description** 
Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

http://api.jquery.com/find/